# Solidity compiler

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain

i tried to write compiler for new contract. It's in compile.js and contain:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.7;

const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8');

console.log(solc.compile(source, 1));
```

file compile.js is in catalog inbox
file Inbox.sol is in inbox/contracts/Inbox.sol.

invoking a "node compile.js" in console i get:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

as i understand it can't find a source?

Comment: No, it said that there is something unexpected (a syntax error), probably coming from your source contract, maybe there is an error inside

Comment: it's surprising. I thought that it did not find this contract Inbox.sol because when i test compiler and try to put wrong path to the contract, console log information was the same. In this case is this really something wrong with source contract?

Comment: Well if they were no file, `fs.readFileSync()` it should have broke, however i suggest you to look at your source, see if this is your contract then check it directly with the compiler

Comment: Remove the pragma line, your compile file is a JS file, not solidity.

Comment: OMG, of course.. Thank you very much, now everything works!